# Looking for published version of a successful aircraft certification effort

Tags: aircraft-certification

I'm assuming-- and please correct me if I'm wrong-- that at the end of the certification process, the FAA receives a thick binder of materials. Is there an online link to an example of said binder?

- It doesn't really matter how old it is, I'm just looking for something representative.
- If beggars can be choosers, simpler is better: I'd rather peruse a binder for a J-3 than for an A-380.
- The certification authority is not important, e.g. EASA and FAA would be equally good.

Comment: Not sure the info would be public, there is potentially a lot of proprietary design details in the package...

Comment: @MichaelHall I've been wondering about that. I've no idea if design detail confidentiality could/should/would survive an FOIA request. Presumably, it is in the public good to be able to independently verify that certification standards are being met. That being said, I don't want to bloviate on what *could be*.

Comment: It's more like a endless stream of reports.  Qualification test reports, Endurance test reports, Structural test reports, System safety analysis reports, Flight test reports and on ad infinitum. On a transport airplane the cert package will fill a room.  On a light plane, maybe just a bookshelf.

Comment: Good point by John K.  I've only been involved in certifying electronic components, but one part could fill a few binders.  And to my earlier remark, the test plans and reports tend to not have much design details, more performance requirements and qualification test levels achieved.

Comment: @MichaelHall "performance requirements and qualification test levels achieved" <-- Those are exactly the kinds of reports I'm interested in reading. I'd like to see how the reports look and feel, how extensive the proofs are, etc... The rabbit-hole of "Yeah, but did you *really* prove it? What about the test machine's calibration? What about the calibration machine's calibration? What about..." is potentially infinite, so I'm interested in what best practices look like.